# Go - Efficient way of converting float to pgtype.Numeric

Tags: go, pgx

I am using `github.com/jackc/pgx/v5`. In `v4` we had a Numeric.Set() method that we could use in the following way:

```
var num &pgtype.Numeric{}
num.Set(4.35)
```

However in `v5` there is no more `Set()` method. [See repo here](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/master/pgtype/numeric.go).

So, how do we create `Numeric` objects in `v5`? Are we supposed to use this way:

```
   
    // This is equivalent to 5.43
    num := pgtype.Numeric{
    Int: big.NewInt(543), 
    Exp: -2, 
    Status: pgtype.Present
    }
```

Is there any other way around? Of course, other than implementing it myself. Don't take me wrong I have nothing against writing the code, I just want to know if there's already a way to do this and if I am on the right track.

Comment: You could check the repo's history to find out when it was removed and why. I could imagine that creating a numeric value from a float was just moved.

Comment: I just did, following your comment and I found the exact point where it was changed. I also saw in the discussions of the repo a few comments by jackc (the dev) saying it is no longer needed. However I still cannot find how to use them now.

Comment: Okay, just checked in some own `pgx` code: I'm not using `Numeric` there at all. If I understand this correctly, it is rather an internal thing, an implementation detail and not part of the API. I can't say for sure though, because my code still uses v4. Maybe I'll get around to updating it these days.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the tests, you could still use `Scan`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgtype"
)

func main() {
    var x pgtype.Numeric

    if err := x.Scan("4.35"); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    log.Printf("x: %+v", x)
}
```

Your use case seems to be quite unique. Typically this is used to convert the Postgres `NUMERIC` response to compatible go types.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am asking this question because I am using `sqlc` a query builder to interact with the database. My issue is `sqlc` generates the params for their functions using pgtypes. Here is a better explanation of what I mean, if you have the time to check it out. https://github.com/sqlc-dev/sqlc/discussions/2910

Comment: @KarlsMaranjs Still relevant

Comment: @m_ocean we ended up creating helper functions :(

Comment: @KarlsMaranjs Yeah, me too... So far, the best way for me seems to be to format a float into a string (with the required number of precision digits) and then scan that string into a pgtype.Numeric, as shown in the answer.